# Is it OK to redistribute the utility installutil that ships with .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a .NET service built with C# and it requires install util to be properly installed. However I don't trust that it's always in the right place when my installer runs on a customer's machine. Does Microsoft allow you to freely redistribute installutil with your products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it is part of the .Net distribution package, so it should be there already on any machine that has .Net installed.  And if your install msi has a module to do the .Net install for whichever CLR version your app requires, then that will install the InstallUtil for you...

Answer (score 0):

It should be ok, is it not part of the .net framework redistributable which is free? you can always just copy it from the framework folder before calling it, assuming the framework is always in the same place?